# PHP foreach glob to load PDFs from NAS Storage

Tags: php, foreach, nas

I want to create a code using php `foreach (glob())` that will load my pdf files from a Network Attach Storage (NAS) is this possible? or there are other option can be used other than using `foreach (glob())`...

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Forecast</th>
            <th>Date Issued</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Action</th>                                          
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach(glob("pdf/*.pdf") as $file)  { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $file; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a></td>
        <td>ss</td>
        <td>wdwad</td>
        <td>adwwad</td>
        <td>wdawd</td>            
        <td>dwa</td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>                  
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your NAS. If you can access a directory on the NAS, like on your local disk, php won't even know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Guntram, it is totally possible. However it has nothing to do with PHP or coding.

You will have to mount the NAS pdf directory, so it is accessible on the web server running your PHP. You can look at [NFS](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [SSHFS](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell_file_system).

Once you have mounted your NAS pdf directory into your local `/path/to/pdf`, then you can `glob("/path/to/pdf/*.pdf")`, because your webserver will consider them to be local files.

Comment: Thank you i already load the data that i need in my system  but im having a problem again because i cant open the data that i load.. but i have my this "href" code in my system ....   <td><a href="<?php echo $file; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a></td>

Comment: What is in your `$file` variable? You need a path inside your webserver document root. For example if you website document root is `/var/www/` you can't have a `href` link pointing to `/home/documents/pdf`. What you can do is `file_get_contents` the pdf file dans dump it to the user so he can download it.